# How do I authenticate the with the Google Storage SDK using a JSON service account key?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I'm having a look at the API reference located at:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html

How am I meant to authenticate when using a service account? I don't see how to create the necessary `Credentials` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    '/path/to/key.json')

scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
```

Comment: Or with the environment variable, which is the first option even on that page (you're only showing the second option).